# Can tsqlt be used with parallel data warehouse?

Tags: unit-testing, tsqlt, database-testing, parallel-data-warehouse

Saw that CLR functions needed to be enabled to use tsqlt.
Can I actually use it in PDW ?

Or any other ways or tools to perform unit testing on PDW ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

There's no way around the CLR requirement, so you need to find an alternative tool.

Depending on your workflow, either the "SQL Server Unit Tests" (which are .NET unit tests) built into Visual Studio, or something like [DBFit](http://dbfit.github.io/dbfit/) might be more appropriate.

The downside of either of these is that you don't get the mocking facilities of tSQLt, so you'll need to be a bit more careful about test setup/teardown.